# ¿Cómo consigo una secuencia de números seguidos?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

¿Cómo consigo que se escriba la siguiente secuencia?

```
2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24
```

Adjunto la fórmula con la que estoy intentando conseguir el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: copia mejor el código como texto en lugar de imagen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que quieres lo puedes conseguir de la siguiente forma:

```
for n  in `seq 12`
do  
   echo -n "$((n*2)) "
done

echo
```

El resultado es: 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22  24

La siguiente versión es como la que has estado haciendo:

```
array="1 2 3  4  5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12";
doble=2
for n  in  $array
do  
   echo -n "$((n*doble)) "
done
echo
```

Comment: Correctísimo, ¡muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 2):

Esto lo implementa `seq` directamente, que tiene la sintaxis:

```
seq <valor_inicial> <diferencia_entre_números> <valor_final>
```

Por ello, simplemente debes decir `seq 2 2 24`:

```
$ seq 2 2 24
2
4
6
8
...
24
```